# For loop only running when debugging (eclipse) & variations each run

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, loops, user-interface

I'm trying to create a series of concentric circle  outlines that have different colours (that are random) and have written a script to achieve this. The problem is that when I run the program  only *one* circle is drawn. However when I step through the code the circles appear as I would want them to, until I click resume at which point the code messes up slightly again. I'm at a loss as debugging seems to be the only way to diagnose problems but also seems to be the only way the script remotely works. 
I tried to see whether the loop is actually being skipped somehow by making the system print the variable *i* every cycle which made more than one circle appear, however still only 3 or 4, the point to take from this being it varies! Every time I run the script I get a different amount of circles which is leading me to believe something very strange is going on, something too strange for me to just figure out intuitively. Thanks for reading and here is the script (I advise people to copy this into eclipse and see what output they get). P.S. I know the circles aren't concentric but this is the least of my worries for now.
**Questions**:
1) Why does it appear that the for loop is being skipped when this script is run?
2) Why when I make the system print something every loop does this slightly fix the problem but still give rise to this random variation?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CircleGenerator {
    private int outerDiameter;
    private int innerDiameter;
    private int colorRange;
    private Color bgColor;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    //private JButton nextCircleButton;
    private CircleDrawer drawer;

    public CircleGenerator(int outer, int inner, int colorRange, Color bgColor) {
        this.outerDiameter = outer;
        this.innerDiameter = inner;
        this.colorRange = colorRange;
        this.bgColor = bgColor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircleGenerator myGenerator = new CircleGenerator(300,20,200,Color.RED);
        myGenerator.setupGUI();
        myGenerator.genCircle();
    }
    public void setupGUI() {
        // Sets up the environment for the circles to be drawn
        frame = new JFrame("Beautiful Circles");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBackground(bgColor);
        //JButton nextCircleButton = new JButton("Next Circle");          //will use later to regenerate more circles
        drawer = new CircleDrawer();
        //mainPanel.add(drawer);
        frame.getContentPane().add(drawer);
        frame.setSize(outerDiameter+innerDiameter, outerDiameter+innerDiameter+20);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void genCircle() {
        // generate the necessary parameters to send to the Circle Drawer
        for (int i = innerDiameter; i < outerDiameter+1; i++) {
            //System.out.println(i);      //REMOVE THIS TO GET THE VARIATION!!!!
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * colorRange) + 1;
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * colorRange + 1);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * colorRange + 1);
            //int x = i - innerDiameter;
            //int y = frame.getContentPane().getHeight() - i;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            drawer.updateValues(i, x, y, red, green, blue);
            drawer.repaint();
        }

    }

    class CircleDrawer extends JPanel {
        private int diameter;
        private int x;       //  the two x and y values are for the
        private int y;       //  coordinates of the upper left corner of the oval.
        private int red;
        private int green;
        private int blue;

        void updateValues(int diameter, int x, int y, int red, int green, int blue) {
            this.diameter = diameter;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.red = red;
            this.green = green;
            this.blue = blue;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(new Color(red,green,blue));
            g.drawOval(x,y,diameter,diameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why post this down? What on earth is wrong with this question?

Comment: I'll edit the post and try to be more precise, but essentially what I mean is that the purpose of the loop is to draw a circle each time round, with a different diameter each time. When I simply run the application I only see one circle as if the loop has only iterated once.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be strange but I have a rapid response for you. Try this:

```
private void genCircle()
{
    // generate the necessary parameters to send to the Circle Drawer
    for (int i = innerDiameter; i < outerDiameter + 1; i++)
    {
        //System.out.println(i); //REMOVE THIS TO GET THE VARIATION!!!!
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * colorRange) + 1;
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * colorRange + 1);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * colorRange + 1);
        // int x = i - innerDiameter;
        // int y = frame.getContentPane().getHeight() - i;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        drawer.updateValues(i, x, y, red, green, blue);
        drawer.repaint();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }
}
```

If you want to see something you must give some time to the AWT thread to do his job.

Comment: When you say strange do you mean badly written? If so in which way; would greatly appreciate the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

An other solution (cleaner) could be:

```
public class CircleGenerator
{
    private int outerDiameter;
    private int innerDiameter;
    private int colorRange;
    private Color bgColor;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private CircleDrawer drawer;

    public CircleGenerator(int outer, int inner, int colorRange, Color bgColor)
    {
        this.outerDiameter = outer;
        this.innerDiameter = inner;
        this.colorRange = colorRange;
        this.bgColor = bgColor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CircleGenerator myGenerator = new CircleGenerator(300, 20, 200, Color.RED);
        myGenerator.setupGUI();
    }

    public void setupGUI()
    {
        // Sets up the environment for the circles to be drawn
        frame = new JFrame("Beautiful Circles");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBackground(bgColor);
        // JButton nextCircleButton = new JButton("Next Circle"); //will use later to regenerate more circles
        drawer = new CircleDrawer();
        // mainPanel.add(drawer);
        frame.getContentPane().add(drawer);
        frame.setSize(outerDiameter + innerDiameter, outerDiameter + innerDiameter + 20);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class CircleDrawer extends JPanel
    {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            // generate the necessary parameters to send to the Circle Drawer
            for (int i = innerDiameter; i < outerDiameter + 1; i++)
            {
                int red   = (int) (Math.random() * colorRange) + 1;
                int green = (int) (Math.random() * colorRange + 1);
                int blue  = (int) (Math.random() * colorRange + 1);
                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;

                g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
                g.drawOval(x, y, i, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Draw circles is done in the paint method. The paint method in this case, is to draw all the circles not only one.
Note that generally, the use of repaint() method is not necessary even banned. You should use invalidate() to say that your drawing job is finished and then the AWT thread could draw the entire scene. Do not forget that you are in the AWT thread.